# Prove not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity 1, such that $R$ contains exactly three ideals:$\{0\},J,R$. Prove that $R$ is not an integral domain.

I was thinking start with supposing that R is an integral domain, then for $ab=0, a=0,b \ne0$ for $b \in R-J$, it can found a contradiction of proving $Rb$ is also  an ideal. But I cannot go on anymore, may be I was thinking wrong and hope some body can help me with it. Thanks

Comment: $Rb$ is always an ideal. In the case $b \in R-J$, it must necessarily be all of $R$. I think you'll find you'll get a little more luck by considering $b \in J-\{0\}$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think I made some mistake, yes, it will be more obvious if $b \in J-\{0\}$, but what if $b \in R-J$? I think I am not doing right

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it will be more obvious" there. Can you figure out why for $b \in R-J$, it must be the case that $Rb=R$? What must $Rb$ be if $b \in J-\{0\}$? This isn't a solution; just a hint on what things you should study in attempting to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b \neq 0$ be in $J$. The ideal generated by $b$ is a nonzero subideal of $J$, and hence must equal $J$. Now, look at $b^2$. If $b^2=0$ then we are done.

Otherwise, ideal generated by $b^2= J$ and hence there exists $r \in R$ such that $b=rb^2$. But then, $b(1-rb)=0$ and $1-rb \neq 0$ as otherwise $J$ is not a proper ideal.

Comment: but what if $b$ is in $R-J$ why we don't need to discuss about that?

Comment: We only need to show that there exists two non zero elements whose product is $0$. Note that any element in $R-J$ is actually invertible. Can you prove it?

Comment: Yes, I can prove that. Because $Rb$ is exactly $R$, so there is an element $rb=1$.